# Match unlist output against set of column names

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
main.data <- c("id","num","open","close","char","gene","valid")
data.step.1 <- list(id="12",num="00",open="01-01-2015",char="yes",gene="1234",valid="NA")
match.step.1 <- unlist(data.step.1)
```

The `main.data` are the column names of all possible column data.

I have a loop that streams data step-by-step, which could have missing column (list name).

I would like to match the each step (data.step.n) against the master column names (main.data).

Desired output:

```
id      num         open      close     char         gene        valid 
"12"    "00"    "01-01-2015"    ""      "yes"       "1234"         "NA"
```

How can I unlist the data and match it against the names so that if the entry is missing like in this case `close` that would be filled with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 v1 <- setNames(rep('', length(main.data)), main.data)
 v1[main.data %in% names(match.step.1)] <- match.step.1
```

Or use `match`

```
  v1[match(names(match.step.1), main.data)] <- match.step.1
```

Or just use `[`

```
  v2 <- setNames(match.step.1[main.data], main.data)
  v2[is.na(v2)] <- ''
```